# WiFi on Emulator: Error 10038

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am trying to implement some QoS algorithms on the WiFi interface.

```
public class MYActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WifiManager MYManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo MYInfo = MYManager.getConnectionInfo();
        TextView MYLinkSpeed = new TextView(this);
        MYLinkSpeed.setText(Integer.toString(MYInfo.getLinkSpeed()));
    }
}
```

However the app "force closes" on the emulator with the following message on the Eclipse console.

> java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10038 nor
>   current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.

Using "F8" function to enable/disable Wi-Fi does not help.
The "uses-permissions" are set in the manifest correctly.

Here is my AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
          package="com.MY" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"> 
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" /> 
    <application> 
        <!-- ... -->
    </application> 
</manifest>
```

Comment: Don't see anything wrong - can you post your manifest too please? Maybe the permission is not in the right place or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, edited that into your question. Also can't see anything wrong. It might be that the emulators wifi features are somewhat limited, I can't say for sure though since I almost exclusively test on physical devices. Maybe someone else knows more, wait a while. :)

Comment: @ALEXTSC - Please find the manifest below:  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    package="com.MY"  
    android:versionCode="1"  
    android:versionName="1.0" >  
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />  
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />  
    <application  
        ......            
    </application>  
</manifest>

Comment: @alextsc - thanks.  I loaded the .apk on to my phone (samsung ace froyo) and the problem persists. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your manifest the problem is so obvious from the log you dont have the permission for wifi state listening.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: Nevermind. I can't read. Sorry, you are right. Totally overlooked the different permission names.

Comment: If your problem is solved mark this post as the answer please thanks.